# What process does certbot run as on Linux?

Tags: linux, security, ssl, certbot

I'm guessing certbot must operate as a continual running service on Linux however using `ps` on a server that uses Let's Encrypt certificate auto-renewal, I'm not seeing any obvious process for certbot. If it's running successfully, is there a central process for certbot, and if so, what is it?

I can find the version with `apt-cache policy certbot | grep Installed` - in my case `0.25.0-1~bpo9+1`

Answer (score 10):

Certbot is a **Python** program. So it runs as some version of python3 (currently minimum version supported is 3.6).

And, notice it doesn't run for most of the time. It is started periodically by **cron** or **systemd-timers** (whichever is used on your system), checks and renews certficates and stops.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't need to run continually, and that would be slightly wasteful of system resources. Certificates can be renewed before they expire, so it's enough to just check every now and again if there are any that the system knows about which need to be renewed.